# windows bat files: a %random% number as answer to an question

Tags: windows, file, random, batch-file, if-statement

i am making a simple little text game in a bat file.
now, i reached a point where i want the bat file to generate a random number (using %random%); and then it will popup for 2 secs (using echo and timeout). then you should enter it in a if /p .
if you enter the right one, it will goto sb3. if its not the right one, it will goto gameover.
is this even possible?

```
cls
echo remember these
set ran=%random%
echo %ran%
timeout 2
cls
set /p sb2=what was the numbers? if you fail the game will quit.
if %sb2%==%ran% goto sb3
```

currently, whatever you type will proceed to sb3.

Comment: I think it should say something like `if you fail then I will cry.`

Comment: The batch file should contain one command: `echo Please install python`

Comment: GregS: For something this simple? I don't think so.

Answer (score 5):

Do you have a code path for the alternative? If you just have the `if ... goto` then it will just continue with the next statement if the condition wasn't met. If your code looks like this:

```
 if %sb2%==%ran% goto sb3
 :sb3
 ...
```

then it's not surprising that you'll always end up there.

You need to jump out explicitly:

```
 if %sb2%==%ran% goto sb3
 goto :eof
 :sb3
 ...
```

Comment: thanks! it worked, i had the :sb3 before but i didnt have another goto if it wasnt the right!

Comment: Think of it as an »if (condition) then do something« with an implicit »else just continue« at the end :-)